# Export Graphics using Move in Optica

Tags: graphics, export, animation, commercial-package, optics

I am modeling an eye and am using `TurboPlot` and `DrawSystem`.

I would like to export the graph, but using the `Move` function which returns a `Graphics`. When execute `Show[Graphics[%]]` I just get a graph, without the object and when I export get the following error:

> ```
> Show::gtype: Optical System is not a type of graphic,
> ```

And this leads me to the questions:

**1)** Is there an alternative to the `Move` function, or similar to `Move`, which gives an option to `Export` a graph?

**2)** Is there a function that will let me `Export` a graph even with the function `Move`?

```
colorscreen = CustomDeflections[Screen[0.9], Function[Ray[WaveLength -> .45]], 
                AddTo -> ChangedRay];

myplot = DrawSystem[{ConeOfRays[20, NumberOfRays -> 7],
    RefractiveIndex [1.5], Polarization [45], 
    Ray [WaveLength -> .45, AddTo -> NewRay],
    Move[SphericalLens[{rr1, 5}, {rr2, -5}, 3, 0.5], {x, 5}, SaveDefinitions -> True],
    Move[PinHole[0.5, 1.5], 7],
    Boundary[{0, -4, -4}, {15, 4, 4}],
    Move [Screen[5, " "], 15],
    Move[Screen [1.5], 5], ColorView -> Long [Intensity], 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, SaveDefinitions -> True}];

 Show[Graphics[%]]
```

> ```
> Move::pattern: The pattern HoldForm[colorscreen,1] is not recognized by Move.
> ```

```
 Export["myplot.jpg", myplot]
```

Comment: Plus there will be a limited supply of Optica users, so you should entice them just so much more.

Comment: Have you tried to post this on Wolfram Community?

Comment: I have no look into Wolfran Community, I will try

Comment: Are you drawing a 3D figure by any chance? In that case you should use `Graphics3D` instead of `Graphics`.

Comment: Optica respond and they said can be save using click and save, but doed not save nice .jpg, the suggest to save is a .pdf

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the `OutputType` option, which allows you to specify Graphics output instead of the default Optical System output from functions like `AnalyzeSystem`, `DrawSystem`, and `ShowSystem`.

```
mySystem = DrawSystem[{ConeOfRays[20, NumberOfRays -> 7],
    RefractiveIndex[1.5],
    Polarization[45],
    Ray[WaveLength -> .45, AddTo -> NewRay], 
    Move[SphericalLens[{rr1, 5}, {rr2, -5}, 3, 0.5], {x, 5}, SaveDefinitions -> True],
    Move[PinHole[0.5, 1.5], 7], 
    Boundary[{0, -4, -4}, {15, 4, 4}],
    Move[Screen[5, " "], 15], 
    Move[Screen[1.5], 5], SaveDefinitions -> True}];

myPlot = ShowSystem[myplot, PlotType -> Full3D, ColorView -> Intensity, 
 OutputType -> StandardGraphics];

Show@Graphics@myPlot
```

[image]

Comment: I've created a new tag [tag:optics] and tagged this question with it. You should be able to retag other questions that are optics related :)

Comment: @TheToad - Thanks. I just submitted a description for the new tag.